# How can I put an image at the end of row 1 and start of row 2?

Tags: css, css-grid

[image: Preview]

This is the best preview I can provide. I want to do something exactly like this with CSS Grid Layout if possible. I also want it to be responsive. This is the start code:

```
.wrapper { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
}

.background-image {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.image {
  grid-column: 2 / span 3;
}
```

Now I have played around with `grid-template-rows` and `grid-row` in so many ways but I cant get it to work. The first thing maybe you could do is try fixed rows like this:

```
grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 1fr
```

and then do

```
.background-image {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.image {
  grid-column: 2 / span 3;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b5aujgq7/1/

But since I want it to be responsive when the screen gets smaller, the `background-image` is way smaller and 200px no longer works as it's too much. I need the first 2 rows to be `fr` so they have the same height as the images.

I think I have a solution but I don't know how to implement it: make row 1 70% of its content (background-image).

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Comment: Could you provide a demo (jsfiddle, codepen...) and ideally a stack snippet with the code you're working with. It'll be easier for us to help. thanks

Comment: Frankly, I'd sugegst that *natively* this is not what CSS-Grid would manage. Positioning or negative margins might be better.

Comment: @sol https://jsfiddle.net/b5aujgq7/1/ with the solution "fixed" rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not define just 4 rows, assign the first 2 to the background, and the 3rd and fourth to the image ?

```css
#main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat (4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
}

.background-image {
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: 2 / span 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}
```

```html
<section id="main">
  <img class="background-image" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1400_and_h450_bestv2/askg3SMvhqEl4OL52YuvdtY40Yb.jpg">
  <img class="image" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/eKi8dIrr8voobbaGzDpe8w0PVbC.jpg">
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep it simple with CSS positioning properties inside your grid:

[revised fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b5aujgq7/2/)

```css
#main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  position: relative;
}

.background-image {
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;

}
```

```html
<section id="main">
  <img class="background-image" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1400_and_h450_bestv2/askg3SMvhqEl4OL52YuvdtY40Yb.jpg">
  <img class="image" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/eKi8dIrr8voobbaGzDpe8w0PVbC.jpg">
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you Micheal. But I used @vals solution instead.